# Kernel of Linear Transformations Question

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ represent a linear transformation such that $\ker(T)=\ker(T\circ T)$, prove that:

$$\ker(T\circ T)=\ker(T\circ T \circ T)$$

I tried to prove this using the standard matrix:

Let $A$ represent the standard matrix of $T$, then we can deduce that:

$Ax=A^2x=0$, for some vector $x\in\mathbb R^n$, since $\ker(T)=\ker(T\circ T)$.

Multipliying $A$ to the equality gives me $A^2x=A^3x=0$, therefore $\ker(T\circ T) = \ker(T\circ T \circ T)$

Am I missing anything out in this proof? Is there any other way to prove this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Perhaps trying to show that $\ker T^3 \subset \ker T^2$ and $\ker T^2 \subset \ker T^3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}$ $x \in \Ker T^2$. We have:

$$T^3x = T(T^2x) = T(0) = 0$$

so $x \in \Ker T^3$. We conclude $\Ker T^2 \subseteq \Ker T^3$.

Now let $x \in \Ker T^3$. We have:

$$0 = T^3x = T^2(Tx)$$

This implies $Tx \in \Ker T^2 = \Ker T$. Hence, $T^2x = T(Tx) = 0$, so $x \in \Ker T^2$. We conclude $\Ker T^3 \subseteq \Ker T^2$.

Therefore, $\Ker T^2 =\Ker T^3$.

Comment: Ahh Beat me to it. +1 Well written